# ZIP file not opening (corrupted)

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, zip, archive, corruption

I have been tasked with fixing a corrupted zipfile - the clue I have been given is to change its file header. I looked at the hex bytes using gHex and changed 50 4B 05 06 to 50 4B 03 04 but it's still not working - I just get the failure message "Error while loading the archive." Does anyone know why this is or how I can fix it?

Comment: What is `VMWare Archive Manager`?

Comment: The program I'm taking part in has provided a VMWare Virtual Machine equipped with tools to help me solve challenges - Archive Manager is the part of the File Management system that opens ZIP archive data. I think the problem is less about Archive Manager malfunctioning but more about how to fix the zipfile to eliminate this error.

Comment: OK - in that case, you should probably rephrase your question title.

Comment: Ok, I've done that. Can you help me?

Comment: Sorry, it's not an area of expertise for me. I rarely use zips anymore.

Comment: Can you test the original zip file using the Linux `unzip` command? Run `unzip -t filename.zip` and post what it outputs.

Comment: Archive:  masterkey-x86
error [masterkey-x86]:  missing 4 bytes in zipfile
  (attempting to process anyway)
error [masterkey-x86]:  attempt to seek before beginning of zipfile
  (please check that you have transferred or created the zipfile in the
  appropriate BINARY mode and that you have compiled UnZip properly)
  (attempting to re-compensate)
warning: filename too long--truncating.
bad extra field length (local)
At least one error was detected in masterkey-x86. ~ Yeah, it seems something is wrong with the hex bytes after all. Thanks for letting me know about that unzip command btw